# The argument type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RenderObject' because 'RenderObject?' is nullable and 'RenderObject' isn't

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, customscrollview, scrollcontroller

I am creating a web with Flutter web and I would like to implement a button that automatically scrolls the view down to a certain widget. For this I am using a scroll controller and a global key

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
final _key = GlobalKey();
```

that I assigned to the desired container

```
Widget contact() {    
    return Container(
      key: _key,
      ...
    );
}
```

This is my main Scaffold. I am using a CustomScrollView:

```
   return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          NavBar(navBarBackground()),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                imageAndText(),
                highlights(),
                androidIosDesktop(),
                multiplatform(),
                phrase(),
                contact(),
                const Footer(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

and I am trying to implement this function for the button

```
    void jump() {
      _scrollController.position.ensureVisible(
        _key.currentContext.findRenderObject(),
        alignment: 0.5,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      );
    }
```

but I get an error on `_key.currentContext.findRenderObject()` due to null safety.

[image: error output]

It says that I should add a null check to the target but I do not know where I should do it. I tried with the key but it does not work there. (I already tried writing ?. but that still gives an error)
[image: ide help]

Any idea how to solve this error, or maybe how to scroll down to a specific widget in another way? (I already tried jumping to offset but I prefer this approach since I don't have to worry about changing any dimensions).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to `_key.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!` if you sure it cannot be null

Comment: I tried doing it there but it still throws an error: The method 'findRenderObject' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i edited my answer